# Why did Edmure Tully agree to this plan?

Tags: game-of-thrones

[Edmure](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Edmure_Tully) was set free by Jaime. He could have just held the Riverlands.

Yet he chose to go back in his cage and betray his own men to ensure that his child could live.

That's kind of idiotic isn't it?

His son, whom he never saw, is  Walder Frey's grandson. He shouldn't fear that they will murder his son. Yet he takes a much greater risk and forgoes his freedom just so Jaime doesn't murder his son.

If I were him, I'd just enjoy my freedom and father more sons on other women than Roslin Frey.

Comment: because he has honour? unlike the kingslayer...

Comment: Idk man. Ask your father, or any father.

Comment: He *didn't* give it away. He's basically a hostage in his own home. He *wasn't* set free by Jamie, he was sent on a mission under orders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few incorrect assumptions in your question, so I will address them here:

> **Edmure was set free by Jaime.**

[Edmure](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Edmure_Tully) was *not* set free by [Jaime](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jaime_Lannister). Jaime had ordered (off-screen) for Edmure to re-enter Riverrun and open the gates from the inside.

> Jaime meets Edmure in the tent where he is being imprisoned and implores him to appeal to his uncle to surrender Riverrun. 
>   ...
> Jaime offers to reunite him with his wife and son and have him live out his days in gentle imprisonment as a hostage at Casterly Rock.<sup>[[1]](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Edmure_Tully#Season_6)</sup>

He didn't *choose* any of this, he was forced to do it at <strike>gun-point</strike> sword-point.

> **That's kind of idiot isn't it?**

No it isn't; he's lost *everything* - his [father](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Hoster_Tully), his sisters ([Catelyn](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Catelyn_Stark) and [Lysa](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Lysa_Arryn)), his [lands](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Riverlands) and his [home](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Riverrun). The only thing left in his life are his [wife](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Roslin_Tully) (whom he actually liked), and his son whom he's never met. He's chosen to defend them and their lives over the lands of Riverrun and his uncle, the [Blackfish](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Brynden_Tully).

> **He shouldn't fear that they will murder his son.**

Yes he *should*. In Westeros, family, heritage and legacy are all that matters. His son, whether Frey or not is his only chance at surviving the world and having a meaningful life. In fact, the Tully words are "Family, Duty, Honour"<sup>[[2]](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Tully)</sup>, so keeping his family safe is his utmost duty.

> **If I were him, I'll just enjoy my freedom and father more sons on other women than Roslin Frey.**

Well, he's not *you*. He has chosen to save his family and to give them a chance at a peaceful life. Not everyone is as frivolous with their family tree as [Walder Frey](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Walder_Frey). Walder has many children which he's fathered by many women<sup>[[3]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Walder_Frey#Descendants)</sup>. If Edmure was to simply drop his wife and child and "just make new ones", he'd be no better than Walder!

Comment: Would have been +1 anyways but specifically for the "Family, Duty, Honour" point.

Comment: @Aegon Thank you. Also, it can be said that even though Edmure is not the brightest tool in the shed, he's still #TullyAF

Comment: He has family. Blackfish is his uncle. He has a large family. He's a member of a big house.

Comment: @JimThio What family? Where? The Tullys were never a "large house", as far as numbers go, let alone in recent times.

Comment: Jaime may have told Edmure to do so. But once Edmure is in the castle he doesn't have to obey Jaime. That is the problem. As for his son he never see and his wife? Well, I wouldn't trust Jaime if I were him. Jaime can simply lie.

Comment: Jaime CAN simply lie. But Edmure isn't in any position to do anything if he does. Even if Jaime doesn't lie and Edmure doesn't acquiesce, his will to kill every Tully if that's what it takes is likely to mean his death and the snuffing of the Tully line. Edmure's only real hope of anything good coming out for both him and his wife/son and his bannermen who are inside the castle is to go along and hope that Jaime keeps his word anyway - he has nothing to lose. What are you envisioning by him "enjoying his freedom?" If he doesn't turn over Riverrun, Jaime sieges and kills everyone.

Comment: @DariM Perfect comment, my thoughts exactly. Jamie's ultimatum was basically "Either I kill all of you now, or later; OR you give up Riverrun peacefully". Edmure chose the latter.

Answer (score 6):

### Blackfish's quest to find a worthy death

Blackfish was fighting for an honourable death which would be worthy of a Tully of Riverrun. He had no wife or children to consider. He had absolutely nothing to lose which is why he was defiant despite being offered peace by Jaime. He never wanted peace, he just wanted death for himself. That's the only thing the old man wanted.

### Edmure and the quest to keep Tully name alive

Edmure however was married and had a Child. He and his child are future of House Tully. If they die, House Tully dies with them because Brynden is unlikely to reproduce given his celibacy, his advanced age and him being besieged. If House Tully dies, what does it matter who holds Riverrun?

But if they live, the hope of one day getting Riverrun back is alive as well. Edmure chose that instead of going down as the heroic last Lord of Riverrun.

### Walder Frey's kinship to Edmure's kid

You are saying Walder Frey would not kill his grandson but you are forgetting something, It wasn't the Freys who were calling the shots, it was the Lannisters. Walder Frey would not be able to defy a command by Jaime to hand over the child. It would be better for Walder anyways because the babe would be a Tully claimant to the Riverlands and with him dead, Frey hold could be more secure.

### The hopeless situation

Jaime had the numbers to take the castle by storming its walls. He made it clear to Edmure that he did not care how many men died taking the Castle but eventually he will take the Castle. So what's the point of getting your child killed and then getting yourself killed anyways? That's something that would be kind of silly. Abandoning a besieged castle, surrounded by enemies with no prospect of a relief or victory is something which I would call smart.

Comment: +1 Especially for: `"the hope of one day getting Riverrun back"` which is one of the biggest threats to House Frey and Lannister re the Riverlands.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that is looks extremely awful on Edmure's part is that the series completely messed up that part. What happened in the books is much better to understand. That's why even though you don't have the asoiaf tag, I'll quote the books.

**Like in the show, Freys had Edmure on the gallows each day from dawn till dusk.**

That part is the same, and Jaime first made sure Freys stop acting like it.

**Blackfish could resist to the siege.**

This part is different. Due to its location, Riverrun is easy to defend. And in fact, Blackfish did not get it from the Freys, he was already there so he had plenty of time to obtain provisions for a long siege, approximately for two years. With winter approaching, he had a chance of holding the fort.

**Jaime threatened Edmure to yield the castle.**

> "I will assault the castle tomorrow. First I will send the riverlords. You will first be killing your brothers you fought together."

Except Lord Blackwood who did not surrender and except Lord Bracken who were besieging Lord Blackwood all riverlords were there in the siege.

> "Then I will send the Freys. I have no shortage of them."

Frey army was largely intact. They withdrew after Crag has fallen.

> "Only after the last Frey is dead, you'll be fighting against Lannisters."

I think he brought an army around 4000. Soldiers from the Westerlands constituted roughly half of the army.

So, Edmure realized how impossible the situation is. **Jaime offered him an exile in <s>Lannisport</s> Casterly Rock, not a dungeon cell in the Crossing**. He went in there to negotiate a truce with the Blackfish. But he did not attempt to capture Blackfish.

> When Jaime asked where the Blackfish is, Edmure did not respond. After Jaime threatened him with a cell in <s>Lannisport</s> Casterly Rock, he responded "Fish can swim, we opened a gate in the water and he swim through it."

So, as you can see, neither Edmure is a broken idiot nor Blackfish is a romantic fool.